# How to parse 'if, at what moment and on what terms they become legally bound'?

Tags: sentence-meaning, legalese

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p 15.

> • If the purpose of the principle is to allow B to rely on A’s apparent intent, it has
>   been suggested that it should be necessary to show that B has relied in some way:
>   see Atiyah (1986a). English law has generally not explicitly required this (although
>   see *The Hannah Blumenthal* (1983)) and it is submitted that its stance is correct.
>   In the commercial world particularly, it is extremely important that A knows **if,
>   at what moment and on what** terms they become legally bound. Accordingly, it is
>   undesirable for A to have to keep B’s actions under review in order to be able to
>   spot if and when B has relied, and so tell if, when and on what terms a contract
>   has been formed with.

The lone comma after **if** fazes me.

I'm guessing that the sentence means: 'It's important that A knows if + he becomes legally bound + at what moment and
on what terms'. Yet this still sounds wrong; **at what moment and
on what terms** sound too vague to conclude a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bolded clause is effectively a conflation of three statements...

> *it is extremely important that A knows **if** he becomes legally bound
>
>   it is extremely important that A knows **at what moment** he becomes legally bound
>
>   it is extremely important that A knows **on what terms** he becomes legally bound*

I think *all* competent speakers would pause after the second element in OP's list *(at what moment)*, so to my mind there should be a comma after it. The writer is presumably misguidedly assuming this is an appropriate context for discarding a potential (but superfluous) [Oxford comma](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-is-the-oxford-comma), but I think doing that in the current context simply makes it more awkward to parse the text in written form.

Comment: +2 for conflation,  -1 for Oxford comma, net gain +1.

Comment: @TRomano: Do you have any other explanation as to why the writer didn't include a comma after ***at what moment**?* I take it if you were speaking the text yourself you would pause at that point - as would the *writer*, so he presumably didn't consider that as a relevant factor in relation to punctuation. Rightly or wrongly, (wrongly, imho, obviously) he must have been applying *some* principle.

Comment: You may be right. My ears do not always understand the British use of the present in subjunctive situations ("if ... he becomes"). I would prefer "that he has become legally bound, at what moment he became legally bound, and  on what terms" --if the idea is to present a list of three important things to know in contracting situations.  "If", to me, always expresses possibility not actuality, and so to my ears his statement begins in the hypothetical yet ends in the actual.

Comment: @TRomano: Well, you're the grammarian, not me. I don't see anything particularly "subjunctive" in OP's example - which would be fine by me if ***becomes*** were replaced by ***became*** anyway. I also don't see how that change would affect the prosody, and by implication the justification for including a second comma.

Comment: I took it to be *to know whether he has been bound, and if so, at what point in time and on what terms*, rather than a list of three things. I saw first the condition (if he has become legally bound...), and then the two further things to be known that follow when that condition is true.

Comment: @TRomano: oic. I suppose there are actually several ways of "parsing" it. Your version leans towards the possibility of rephrasing as *"**If** the defendant becomes legally bound, it is important [that] he knows at what moment and on what terms"*. Neither your rephrasing nor mine here seems to require a comma after *at what moment*, but I still think OP's original does (where all three conditions are things it's important for the defendant to know, as opposed to *two* things he must know ***if*** the first one should happen to be true).

Answer (score 0):

That sentence could be rewritten to be clearer.

In the commercial world particularly, it is extremely important that A know if, and if so, at what moment and on what terms, he has become legally bound.

It is extremely important that A know whether he has become legally bound, and if so, at what moment and on what terms.